# No Android SDK found - Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: android-studio, android-sdk

I'm trying to install Android Studio on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I've downloaded android-sdk-linux, executed it and downloaded files you see in this picture:

Directory: `/home/user/Downloads/android-sdk-linux`:
[image: <code>Directory: /home/user/Downloads/android-sdk-linux</code>]

After that I copied all of those floders to this directory: `/Android/sdk`
Unfortunately when I run `/Android/bin/studio.sh` in bash to execute Android Studio installer I face this:

"Android Studio installer - No Android SDK found":
[image: Android Studio installer - No Android SDK found]

What Should I do now? anybody knows the reason?

Comment: Did you add the new location(s) for the Android executables to your PATH?

Comment: No buddy.. Which PATH?

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/60218/how-to-add-a-directory-to-my-path

Comment: Hi **ubfan1**. I add `/Android/sdk/tools` and `/Android/sdk/platform-tools` to my PATH. But still same error! :-(

Comment: Which SDK (s) did you download?  .../tools/android   and pick the ones you want.  I don't use Studio, so can't offer any more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

**Ubuntu Make**

Ubuntu Make is a command line tool which allows you to download the latest version of popular developer tools on your installation, installing it longside all the required dependencies (which will only ask for root access if you don't have all the required dependencies installed already), enable multi-arch on your system if you are on a 64 bit machine, integrate it with the Unity launcher… Basically, one command to get your system ready to develop with!

**How to use it**

Example: how to install Ubuntu Make and then, Android Studio.

Installing Ubuntu Make

If you are on latest development Ubuntu version, first, add the Ubuntu Make ppa:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, installing Ubuntu Make:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

How to install android-sdk

```
umake android
```

And then, accept the installation path and Google license. It will download, install all requirements alongside Android Studio and latest android SDK itself, then configure and fit it into the system like by adding an Unity launcher icon…

And that's it! Happy Android application hacking on Ubuntu. You will find the familiar experience with the android emulator and sdk manager + auto-updater to always be on the latest.

Source: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make

Comment: Thanks for your instruction **xangua**. Did all of these... STILL SAME ERROR.. IT'S GANNA KILL ME... HELLLLP

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: No Android SDK found :-( click 2nd link in my question to see the error in picture.